# Console application to scheduled on windows server

Tags: windows, console-application

We have a console application that sends email.We want to execute the application at regular intervals using Windows task scheduler.

Does the windows server require any specific software for the console application to be scheduled?

Answer (score 2):

No, there are no particular software requirements for running an .exe file on Task Scheduler. It should be as easy as creating a new basic task, pointing it towards your .exe and setting when it runs.

[Technet page for Task Scheduler](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748993(v=ws.11).aspx)